# How to remove password from password protected and shared excel workbook?(.xlsm file)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, passwords

I have an excel file that I need to crack. My excel version is 2010 but I do not know what version of excel this file is originally made with. This file has the name of file extension, '.xlsm'.

I know the password to open this file, but I do NOT know the rest of the passwords in this file.

This file is protected with passwords in the...

1. Shared workbook: In the 'Share Workbook' > 'Editing', I cannot uncheck the 'Allow changed by one more users....' because this is grayed out.
   And of course, it's protected with password.

   In the window of 'who has this workbook open now:', there's only one name that is myself.
2. In the 'Review' tab, 'Unprotect Sheet' and 'Protect Workbook' are all grayed out.
3. I cannot delete the password to open this file in the 'General Option' when we go to 'Save as' and we see there.
   Because the box is also grayed out, I cannot delete the password that I already know.
4. I see many worksheets hidden and protected when I go to 'File' tab and 'Info'.
5. The VBA projects are all locked: When I alt+F11, and click the vba project, it says 'Project is unviewable'. I cannot see any projects here.

   Please help me.

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a hacker site. There is a reason for security and locking of files; so people who aren't authorized to edit them, can't. Please don't ask us to help you do something that is potentially illegal or unethical. If you know the author of the file, I would suggest asking them.

Comment: This came up in my company recently.  HR has a document created by someone who has since left the company.  He can still use the document but it is not editable given the lock.

Comment: Oh, this is not an illegal activity what so ever. I got this file from my friend of friend, and it is a just personal use. He is now not contacted somehow but as soon as he is reached, all will be solved. However, I personally was interested in the solution. That's all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer that I have seen as acceptable is to copy everything possible out of the document and rebuild it yourself.  Since you have permission to read the file you would only have to worry if there is some copyright protection for the file.

Obviously, this will not be an easy file to rebuild since you have hidden VBA but I think that is all SuperUser can give you.

Comment: Thanks. But copying everything does not work. Thanks anyway.